Dinner set all right?
What's the meaning of " Dinner set all right?" ? This is a sentence from a novel that one person asks another one. Does it mean " was the dinner suitable for you" or " could you digest the food easily" or something else?
I know dinner-set means dinner-service, but here I think it doesn't mean that.
This is the context:

“You should be getting ready. How you feel? You feel all right?”
“Fine.”
“Dinner set all right?”
Tully could not answer. Openmouthed, he waited.
“Billy?”
There was a small airy sigh.
“Eat something?” Babe whispered.
“Oh, my God, you didn’t drink no beer just now, did you?”
A rich rumble rose at last.
“You sick?”
“No.”
“He had a good steak dinner. I took him to a good place, but then you
can get a bad meal anywhere. You didn’t drink no beer out there, did
you?”
“Hell no.”
“All right, don’t get mad. You’re down to a fine edge. That’s good.
Just keep it that way. You’re going to take him.”

It is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.

Looks like a casual/dialect use.  Probably = Did dinner settle in your stomach?  = Do you have no indigestion/stomach ache/nausea

Merriam Webster: 4
a
: to affect one with or as if with weight||
the pudding sets heavily on my stomach Please also use a dictionary before asking or include it with your question.

FYI, this is very informal dialect, not standard English. For example "How you feel? You feel all right?" instead of "How do you feel? Do you feel all right?".

From Lambie's recommendation of M-W, notice the first thing it says under intransitive is "Chiefly dialectical: SIT." Some contexts might substitute "set" where normally "sit" would be used, e.g. "I'm setting in a chair." It's hardly a formal sentence even so, but a less colloquial version that might be a better choice for a learner would be "Is your dinner sitting well?"

I hope you have learned standard English to a very high level first, because otherwise you are going on a funny dialectal detour, in the meantime.

Could be the place setting. That was my first thought. Since she says "Dinner set all right?" before Babe says, "Eat something?" it seems the male has not eaten.
This passage needs more work by the writer for anything to be clear.

Welcome to ELU. Here answering is reserved for factual, objective responses. Your post seems to be essentially a guess. And your observation about the passage in question seems off topic. If you’d like to edit your post, you are welcome to try to improve it.
